# switch to new page on form submit react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have this (in my `contact.js` file).

```
axios
      .post('http://localhost:3000/create', book)
      .then(() => console.log('Created'))
      .then(() => this.props.history.push({Home}))
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
```

It calls this successfully, but now I want to render a new page, which would be `home.js`, in the same folder. I was wondering how I can do this, after it makes the call to the backend. Can I do it from the front end, or does it have to be backend?

Comment: It depends how your FE app looks like. Is that a standard Single Page Application? So just one index.html and everything else is controlled in FE? Or do you use several HTML files for different pages?

If you use a SPA, which I'm assuming you do, you can look into using a Router like https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start 

You can use that to route between different "pages" or components in your app. You can use the history to push a new route after the BE request https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Maybe looking into a new framework is  a little overhead if the goal of this action is only to make a single page refresh :/

Comment: what is {Home} there ?

Comment: This is not really "just" a single page refresh. It's a new page and not doing a proper redirect is just not correct. If a new "framework" (you mean library, since react-router is not a framework) is a little overhead, I'm happy to provide a working fiddle if that helps - alternatively we can do the same behaviour without an external libarary, but I just think that's even more complicated since you have to manage the state yourself.

Comment: Here is an implementation of history.pushState in React without React Router : https://ncoughlin.com/posts/react-navigation-without-react-router/

Answer (score 0):

If the url location of your `home.js` page is '/home', you can trigger a refresh of the page with the `history.pushState` method.

Though, you router descending from your React framework may have some implemented method to accomplish this task too. Keep in mind that the `history` API is access to to the navigator history, allowing you to trigger render of a previous page, a refresh, etc..

You access to the history API by the DOM Window object, for instance a call to the pushState method should look like :

```
window.history.pushState(null, "", "/Home");
```

Otherwise you can also use the location API from the BOM object

```
location.assign('/Home');
```

which is similar to the `window.history.pushState` method

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-bom/javascript-redirect/

Comment: please view my updated question, with the code you mentioned. It performs the call to the backend, but doesn't actually render the new page.

Comment: I see your code, but there is two mistakes : 1 - you must references  the URL of your page e.g. "/Home", and not your Home react component. 2 - you must access to the history API by the window DOM object